# unable to resolve (Could not construct ApplicationDefaultCredentials) for dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

i am trying to integrate dialog flow with laravel project. but it is giving me error

"Could not construct ApplicationDefaultCredentials"

i also setup my service account credentials in env variable like

GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='credentials.json'

still not working

Comment: Please add your code, the full error message and any data needed to recreate the error.

Comment: Could you please refer to this link for setting up authentication https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-dialogflow.
If this does not work for you, then kindly provide the code and the steps that you followed for setting up authentication and integrating Laravel with Dialogflow.